# Concurrency issues writing to multiple SQLite databases simultaneously on different app threads

Tags: c#, sqlite, concurrency

I've done a lot of searching on this, and haven't had a lot of luck. As a test, I've written a C# WinForms app where I spin up a configurable amount of threads and have each thread write a configurable amount of data to a number of tables in a SQLite database created by the thread. So each thread creates it's own SQLite database, and only that thread interacts with it.

What I'm seeing is that there's definitely some performance degradation happening as a result of the concurrency. For example, if I start each thread roughly simultaneously performance writing to SQLite's tables PLUMMETS compared to if I put a random start delay in each thread to spread out their access.

SQLite starts easily fast enough for my tests, I can insert 20,000 rows in a table in a third of a second, but once I start up 250 threads, those same 20,000 rows can takes MINUTES to write to each of the databases.

I've tried a lot of things, including periodic commits, setting Sychronous=Off, using paramaterized queries, etc... and those all help by shorting the amount of time each statement takes (and therefore reducing the change of concurrent activity) but nothing's really solved it and I'm hoping someone can give some advice.

Thanks!
Andy

Comment: You mean, multiple threads writing to different places on the disk at the same time are slower than a single thread?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting the performance to be like for this level of concurrent writes to the same disk?

Comment: Multiple threads, each writing to their own SQLite database that they create through their own SQLite connection, are significantly slower than a single thread writing to a single SQLite database. I obviously expect it to be slower, there's more CPU usage, memory usage, etc... but there's definitely an exploding contention penalty to performance that seems to indicate that somewhere, internally, there's a shared resource within SQLite.

Comment: I agree. I wrote a quick test case in C# using flat files and 250 workers writing 65k records each. Without locking the writes are all done in about a second, with locking all writes are done in about 16 seconds (18 seconds on a SATA3 SSD, surprisingly slower than a WD Green 2TB). I would expect the SQLite case to be slower than this, but not more than 2*N or 3*N, but that's just a clueless guess. I assume the contention is in the library itself, related to handling 250 databases / transactions with a single process. I would try a multi-process approach to see if you observe a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Too much concurrency in writes in any relational database does cause some slowdown. Depending upon the scenario that you are trying to optimize you can do various other things, few I can think of are:

1) create batches instead of concurrent writes, this means if you are expecting a large number of users writing simultaneously, collect their data and flush them down in larger groups, be warned though that this this means, while our queue is collecting if the application goes down, u would lose the data, u can do this for non critical data such as logs.

2) if ur threads need to do other work as well before inserting the data, u can still have our threads and then add a semaphore or something equivalent to the part of the code where insertion takes place, this will limit the concurrency and speed up the entire process.

3) if what u r trying to do is bulk insert via a tool which you are trying to make, then mention that in your question, a lot of mysql dba's will answer our question better than me.

Comment: Here's a simpler explanation of what I'm seeing..
1. I want a WinForms app that creates 500 SQLite databases simultaneously.
2. Each database has 1 table.
3. In that table, in each database I'm going to insert 65,000 rows.
4. To create and write to the SQLite databases simultaneously, my WinForms app starts a thread for each database.
5. Each thread then loops 65,000 times, each loop inserting a row into the table.

Comment: What I'm seeing is:
1. For 1 thread, I get great performance. I can insert 65,000 rows into a single SQLite datbase in around 300 milliseconds.
2. As I increase the # of threads, performance PLUMMETS. By the time I do 50 concurrent threads (writing to 50 different SQLite databases), the inserts take 30 seconds - 1 minute.
3. If I have each thread wait a random amount of time (reducing the contention), performance skyrockets again.

So there's definitely something in this process which is causing a lot of contention. What I don't understand is why, since each thread uses unique conn and db.

Comment: You should batch that 65000 thousand rows into say like a 1000 (experiment with the batch size), after you are done with this, you should see a major performance improvement, after that you should batch the database creation job as well. here you are trying to create 500 simultaneous connections which are running in a loop and opening and creating even more. The sql connection pool might be running out.